# How to remove the sound driver from CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7, audio, remove

I have a centOS minimal installed and it the sound drivers loaded. I would like to remove all the sound drivers from my server. How can I do that? following are the command outputs from my server.

`cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [AudioPCI       ]: ENS1371 - Ensoniq AudioPCI
                      Ensoniq AudioPCI ENS1371 at 0x2080, irq 17`

`lsmod | grep 'snd'
snd_ens1371            25243  0
snd_rawmidi            30871  1 snd_ens1371
snd_seq_device         14356  1 snd_rawmidi
snd_ac97_codec        130605  1 snd_ens1371
ac97_bus               12730  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm               105835  2 snd_ac97_codec,snd_ens1371
snd_timer              29639  1 snd_pcm
snd                    83425  6 snd_ac97_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,sn _ens1371,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15047  1 snd`

`lspci | grep -i audio
02:03.0 Multimedia audio controller: Ensoniq ES1371 / Creative Labs CT2518/ES1373 (rev 02)`

Comment: What output give you commands `systemctl | grep alsa` `systemctl | grep sound` `systemctl | grep pulse` ?

Comment: `systemctl | grep sound
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:11.0-0000:02:03.0-sound-card0.device                              loaded active plugged   ES1371 / Creative Labs CT2518/ES1373 (AudioPCI 64V/128 / Creative CT4810/CT5803/CT5806 [Sound Blaster PCI])
  sound.target                                                                                     loaded active active    Sound Card`

Comment: The other two commands are not displaying any information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add such lines to /etc/modprobe.d/disable-sound.conf

```
blacklist snd_ens1371
blacklist soundcore
blacklist snd
```